# How can I track my android app users detailed statistics?

Tags: android, android-intent, usage-statistics

UsageStatsManager seems to provide general statistics for all apps on your device, however, I am interested in tracking my own apps user detailed statistics. 
For instance, how many seconds does a certain activity stay opened? how many times is it opened? how many times a button is clicked?

Google provides a nice way to report on your app statistics & reports [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en) but this not what I am looking for!

What I am looking for is either an app that plugs in to my intents (which I doubt is viable) OR
another class/package that provides this functionality given that I plug it in my code (more like a usage calculator that attaches to my intent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate google analytics. So easy:

Add this code to MyApplication class (Consts is my private class where is defined property id):

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

   public class MyApplication extends Application {     
        private static Context context; 
        public enum TrackerName {
          APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
          GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
          ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
        }

        HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

        public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
          if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(Consts.ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

          }
          return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
        }

        public void onCreate(){
            super.onCreate();
            MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();  
        }

        public static Context getAppContext() {
            return MyApplication.context;
        }

    }
```

And this code add to your fragment file:

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;


Tracker t = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);       
t.setScreenName("My screen name");
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

1. Google Analytics - http://www.google.co.in/analytics/
2. Parse.com - https://parse.com/products/analytics
3. Flurry Analytics - http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics

Comment: Thanks a lot for the options!

Comment: @hannunehg Always welcome, you can upvote my answer if you are getting solution from my answer.

Comment: Will do so when I get enought reputation... still new to this :D thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com also have free analitycs tool. You can define your own events and then browse them in Web console.

Answer (score 0):

There are no of logging libraries you can choose from as per your need and integrate it in your app. Like Google Analytics, Flurry etc. Search over internet or try below link...

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/57

Answer (score -1):

Integrate Google Analytic for your android App.